# Insurance against flight cancellation due to weather in Canada

Tags: air-travel, canada, insurance, weather-and-climate

I am considering buying insurance against an airline cancelling a flight and not refunding me the money. But before, I would like to weigh the pros and cons of it.

What are the pros and cons of insurance against flight cancellation due to bad weather?

Comment: (cont'd)  am I right in that assumption that an airline can not honour your hard earned ticket merely for weather? Or are they obligated to bump you and all other passengers to future flights and/or just delay the flight even to the next day? I have always assumed and believe I've heard that indeed you can lose your ticket price if bad weather results in a cancelled flight. At first I thought

Comment: (cont'd) that was ridiculously unfair but that doesn't mean it's not true. Is that the case and does all insurance cover that or do I have to look for specific wording? I know you have to really read the fine print which is one reason I hate getting insurance......so many loopholes for them to get out of compensating you after you've been paying premiums for years. Sorry for the long question and hope it wasn't confusing.

Comment: I've edited to ask an actual question (simple though this question is). John, please re-edit if that wasn't what you meant. Vote to reopen.

Comment: Thanks DJClayworth, yes that's what I was asking (in an unbelievably complicated way), thanks for re-wording.  The answers I got below are exactly what I was hoping to hear AND answers my question.

Comment: Would the answer apply to tickets purchased using Air Miles (because they say the Air Miles are non-refundable)?  They could do one of the first two options, but if those are not possible, they may not be able to refund Air Miles like they can cash.  Correct?

Comment: Air Miles are subject to their own rules, which you can read, but in general if you buy a service and the person you buy it from is unable to deliver, they have to return whatever you paid for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have a misconception on how this works.

If an airline cancels a flight, they are obligated to:

- Reaccomodate you on another, later flight *
- Rebook you on another carrier
- Refund your fare.

**Under no circumstances can an airline cancel a flight and keep the money.** **

*This is the most common result by far.

**The one edge case might be if the airline completely ceases operations due to bankruptcy or other situations.

Comment: Thanks, I'm very happy to hear that as I'd been told otherwise (if there's an act of God out of the airline's control, the flight gets cancelled and you're out your money, since you had the option to purchase insurance......so it's on you and not them).  It sounded grossly unfair but life isn't fair, plus its true the airline can't control weather so I though it may be true.  Your answer has further reinforced my decision to forego such insurance but now I'll have much more peace of mind on this.  No more stressing over whether I'm being foolish in not purchasing insurance.  Thanks!

Comment: @John To be clear, there are other rules and cases that govern this.  Also, there a difference between a refundable and non-refundable fare.